# How do you add an image picker into a Sitefinity custom widget editor?

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-4, sitefinity-5

On Sitefinity CMS 4.x or 5.x architecture, how do you add an image picker to a custom widget? Currently I have to enter an image path into a text field. I would prefer to be able to use the standard picker to select an image from a Sitefinity library or to upload a new image.

Answer (score 3):

Sitefinity thunder http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/381fde64-9898-4a5d-ae20-861e119bbf92 can help you create a control designer for an existing control through a Guid property that will select an image, document, or other media field

Here's an example from the thunder documentation: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/create-selectors-for-guid-properties-in-widget-designers

alternatively you could wire this up manually as described in this blog post on selecting sitefinity content in control designers: http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/joshmorales/posts/11-10-05/selecting_sitefinity_4_content_inside_widget_designers.aspx

hope this is helpful!